# SQL Find Value in Database, return if true or not and if true Count if there is duplicate

Tags: c#, sql

I'm making a query that the title implies.

Currently I have this code. My SQL Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CountOf
FROM     Personnel
WHERE  ([First Name] = @FirstName) AND ([Middle Name] = @MiddleName) AND ([Last Name] = @LastName)
GROUP BY [First Name], [Middle Name], [Last Name]
HAVING (COUNT(*) > 0)
```

and C# code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    int i = 0;
    string LastName;
    string FirstName;
    string MiddleName;
    while (i < myDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1)
    {            
        DataGridViewRow r = myDataGridView.Rows[i];
        LastName = r.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        FirstName = r.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        MiddleName = r.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    
        if (queriesTableAdapter.FindEncoded(FirstName, MiddleName, LastName) == null)
        {
            r.Cells[3].Value =  "Not-Encoded";
        }
        else
        {
            r.Cells[3].Value = " Encoded " + queriesTableAdapter.FindEncoded(FirstName, MiddleName, LastName);
        }
        i++;                
    }            
}
```

The query doesn't loop well. It returns `false` after the 1st loop (manually checked all data are encoded).

Comment: Is the provided query is the select command of the grid view data source?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to group this. But looking at the wider aproach there's also some very bizarre logic.. What is the grid showing? Tell me the where clause applicable to the data showing in the grid, that is being looped over (or say if there is none)

Comment: The data in the mydatagridview is different from what is in the database. Basically i want to match the data in the mydatagridview.

Comment: its hard to understand what your goal is here but... if you change your query to select(*),cols ... group by cols you can read the names and duplicate counts in one go. also i would replace the while loop with a for loop..so it is easier to see how i gets changed

Comment: It may be the WHERE.  First try without WHERE and see what you get.  Then add a parenthesis around entire WHERE : WHERE (( ) AND () AND ()).  I've had similar issue in the past.

Comment: So the data in the grid did not come from the database?

Comment: yes the data in this (mydatagridview) did not come form the database

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

NEW SQL Code:

```
SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) AS Expr1 FROM     Personnel WHERE  ([First Name] = @FirstName) AND ([Middle Name] = @MiddleName) AND ([Last Name] = @LastName)
```

C# Code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string LastName;
        string FirstName;
        string MiddleName;
        
        for (int i= 0; i < myDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {

        DataGridViewRow r = myDataGridView.Rows[i];
        LastName = r.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        FirstName = r.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        MiddleName = r.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        
        if ((Boolean)queriesTableAdapter.FindEncoded(FirstName, MiddleName, LastName) == true)
        {
                r.Cells[3].Value = "Encoded" ;
        }
            else
            {
                r.Cells[3].Value = "Not-Encoded" ;
            }
             
        }
        
    }
```

So basically each loop iterates the row till there are no more rows left to iterate.

Still the code don't loop well and only shows the 1st loop as true the rest false.
[image]

Comment: UPDATE: Code is working.....  the paste button[btn1] was the bugged code.